# Ticks callback not displaying strings containing decimal

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to display a formatted string for thousands and million amounts for only certain ticks on a horizantal stacked bar chart.

See line 18 (which works): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sl5pqg

If the line is changed to `const actualAmount = 12500000;`, I am expecting "$12.5M" to be displayed on the first tick point I want to display but it's coming up blank.

Could someone kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine but you need to define [`ticks.autoSkip: false`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration):

```
ticks: {
    ... 
    autoSkip: false,
```

Please have a look at the amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfz11t)

> If `autoSkip` is `true` (default), Chart.js automatically calculates
>   how many labels can be shown and hides labels accordingly. Labels will
>   be rotated up to `maxRotation` before skipping any. Turn `autoSkip`
>   off to show all labels no matter what.